# How to add borders to each pixel in matplolib in python?

Tags: python

I have wrote the below code using matplolib in python to graph the below figure my question is how to add border to each (1*1) pixel and how to add the grid number for each pixel from the array?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title('Satellite 1')
grid=np.array(
[
[
1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,],
[
9,9,10,10,11,11,12,12,13,13,14,14,15,15,16,16,],
[
17,17,18,18,19,19,20,0,21,21,22,0,23,23,24,24,],
[
25,25,26,26,27,27,28,28,29,29,30,30,31,31,32,32,],
[
33,33,34,0,35,35,36,36,37,37,0,38,39,39,40,40,],
[
41,41,41,42,42,42,43,43,43,44,44,44,45,45,45,0,],
]
)

#ax.imshow(grid)
im = plt.imshow(grid, cmap='PuBuGn')



# Move left and bottom spines outward by 10 points
ax.spines['left'].set_position(('outward', 10))
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('outward', 10))

# Hide the right and top spines
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(True)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(True)


# Only show ticks on the left and bottom spines
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
im.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(True)
im.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(True)
ax.set_frame_on(True)

ax.set_aspect('equal')

plt.colorbar(orientation='horizontal')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add rectangles centred on the pixels you want.

To do this:

1. `from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle`
2. define a rectangle like so: `rect = Rectangle((1, 1), width=2, height=3, facecolor='none', edgecolor='b')`
3. add the rectangle to the `ax` variable like so: `ax.add_patch(rect)`

Comment: How to make this added rectangle with the dimension of the duplicated values in the array as in the first row each rectangle will have two pixels, and in the last row each three pixels will be in one rectangle